# Heroku app with Django SQL Explorer not doing queries on Postgres DB

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I have deployed a Django site on Heroku. I have installed `django-sql-explorer` on the site. All is fine on local, but on Heroku, because the database is Postgres, when running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM parcare_parking WHERE parking_on = date('now','+1 day');
```

I get this error:

```
function date(unknown, unknown) does not exist LINE 3: WHERE parking_on = date('now','+1 day'); ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.*

`SELECT * FROM parcare_parking WHERE parking_on = "2018-10-08"` fired

    column "2018-10-08" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM parcare_parking WHERE parking_on = "2018-10-08... ^
```

However `SELECT * FROM parcare_parking` finds correct results.
They were on my local dev, but somehow from my local SQLite3 to Heroku's Postgres is an incompatibility. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> somehow from my local SQLite3 to Heroku's Postgres is an incompatibility. What should I do?

You should use the same database in all environments. Since Heroku doesn't support SQLite, that means a client-server database like PostgreSQL.

Django's ORM helps even out differences between database technologies, but it can't solve everything. Using different databases in different environments significantly increases the chances of having environment-specific bugs like this one.

Comment: I'd love if the downvoter would explain how this is bad advice. Every environment in which a program runs should be a similar as possible to reduce surprise issues. You wouldn't run Django 1.10 in development and Django 1.11 in production, would you? Or develop in Python 3 and deploy using Python 2? Using the same database system in these environments is very important. Even regular database migrations, generated from model changes, can fail in different ways on different databases, e.g. due to the way some engines rollback out of a transaction or handle invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

For other non-sql devs here you go---you have to use single quotes:

```
SELECT *
FROM parcare_parking
WHERE parking_on ='2018-10-08'
```